# Can't install RMagick with rbenv

Tags: rbenv, rmagick

I'm using rbenv on my Ubuntu 10.04 server and I already installed ImageMagick, but I can't get RMagick to install successfully. I get the following error message

```
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to install the development headers for libmagickwand like so:

```
apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Comment: or use whatever package manager exists on your system. If you have Mac homebrew it's `brew install imagemagick`